# Magento 2 front end looks like no css and js after deploying static content

Tags: magento2, css, deploy, content

I'm using magento 2.4.3, and I did a couple putty commands, like upgrade, compile, and now

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

but now the front end is loading apparently without css and js, any help with what might be causing this?

Comment: did you debug in browser, if they are returning 404 or some other error

Comment: have you check .htaccess file in pub/? it doesnot exist then you might have deleted that file mistakenly, so copy that file from your backup and put their.

Comment: @ZahidH Just checked that, and there is the .htaccess file into the pub folder!

Comment: great, check log files by date

Comment: If I compile, I get it showing the front end right, but, some of the .js files are not loaded, in fact some functions doesn't work correctly, and if I check the log, I get a lot of "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: " for different .js files

Answer (score 0):

did you add this code in your database ?

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

then run all commands :
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reset

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

then add permission 0777 your project folder